# combining two django models into one form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to make a signup form for teachers and the subjects they teach. I created two different models for them.

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    ...
class Subject(models.Model):
    ...
```

I have a foreign key to connect the subject to teacher since some teachers can teach more that one subject. My problem is I am trying to create the django form of teacher and a subform of subject and a button to add another subject form if necessary. Can anyone point me in a direction to get this done preferable with django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from django.contrib import admin

class SubjectInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Subject

class TeacherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        sublectInline,
    ]
admin.site.register(Teacher, TeacherAdmin)
```

Comment: Thank you very much i have been reading the wrong django documents for 2 days now